# Uniform $L^p$ bound on finite measure implies uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

Suppose that $X$ have finite measure, let $1<p<\infty$, and suppose that $f_n \colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that $\sup_n \int_X |f_n|^p d\mu < \infty$. Show that the sequence $f_n$ is uniformly integrable. In another word, show that
$$\sup_n \int_X |f_n|^p d\mu < \infty \;\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;\; \sup_n \int_{|f_n|>M} |f_n| d\mu \rightarrow 0 \text{ when } M\rightarrow \infty.$$

I have tried using contradiction, but I am not sure how to use the power $p$ in the problem.

I can see why it would work, in some sense, the power $p$ gets rid of the case often called "escape to vertical infinity". For example, define $f_n :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n = n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} $, without the power $p$, we have
$$\sup_n \int_X |f_n| d\mu =1 \;\;\text{ and }\;\; \sup_n \int_{|f_n|>M} |f_n| d\mu =1 \text{ for each } M,$$
but
$$\sup_n \int_X |f_n|^p d\mu = \infty$$

Comment: Use Hölder. ($\int_E |f|\le\Vert f\Vert_p\Vert \chi_E\Vert_q$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra What "particularization" of Hölder is this?

Comment: Is this result false if p = 1?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the inequality
$$\chi\{|f|>R\}\cdot |f(x)|\cdot R^{p-1}\leqslant |f(x)|^p,$$
where $\chi(A)$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A$. Then integrate to obtain
$$\int_{\{|f_n|>R\}}|f_n|\mathrm d\mu(x)\leqslant R^{1-p}\sup_k\int_X\left|f_k(x)\right|^p\mathrm d\mu(x).$$

Comment: Yes, thank you. I used the hint given above $\int_{\{f\geq M\}} f \leq ||f||^p ||\chi_{\{f\geq M\}}||^q$, where $||f||^p$ is finite, and $||\chi_{\{f\geq M\}}||^q$ goes to zero as $m\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Does that inequality have a name?