# $L^2$ bounded implies uniformly integrable

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Below is a paragraph from the book *Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus-Springer* by Jean-François Le Gall. **I don't understand the last sentence, badly circled in red**.

[image]

It is basically claiming that a continuous martingale bounded in $L^2$ with $M_0=0$ is necessarily uniformly integrable.  It suffices to show $M_t$ converges almost surely and in $L^1$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$.   Now the condition does imply that $ M_t^2-\langle M,M\rangle_t$ is  uniformly integrable and also that $E[\langle M,M\rangle_\infty]<\infty$ (this is Prop 4.13 to which the author refers).  So since $\langle M,M\rangle_t$ is nondecreasing this implies $ M_t^2$ converges in $ L^1$ and point wise a.e. But why should this imply the same for $M_t$?  Below is Prop 3.21 to which the author alludes

[image]

Comment: Oh i might be an idiot: if $M_t^2-<M,M>_t$ is uniformly integrable, then so is $M_t^2$ and therefore so is $M_t$?

Comment: It's more basic than that: a family of random variables which is bounded in $L^2$ is uniformly integrable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729217/uniform-lp-bound-on-finite-measure-implies-uniform-integrability)).

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question in the title:

We say that a random process $X$ is $L^{p}$-bounded if
$$
\sup _{n \geq 0}\left\|X_{n}\right\|_{p}<\infty
$$
We say that $X$ is uniformly integrable if
$$
\sup _{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_{n}\right| 1_{\left\{\left|X_{n}\right|>\lambda\right\}}\right) \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { as } \quad \lambda \rightarrow \infty
$$
By Hölder's inequality, for conjugate indices $p, q \in(1, \infty)$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(|X| 1_{A}\right) \leq\|X\|_{p}(\mathbb{P}(A))^{1 / q}
$$
Thus, if $X$ is $L^{p}$-bounded for some $p>1$, then $X$ is uniformly integrable. On the other hand, if $X$ is uniformly integrable, then $X$ is $L^{1}$-bounded.