# Expected distance from origin of random walk on Z^d using multivariate CLT

Tags: random-walk, stochastic-analysis, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to prove that $E[D(X_n, X_0)]$ is roughly equals $ \sqrt{n}~$ using Multivariate Central limit theorem. $$$$
So I represent a d-dimensional simple symmetric random walk $~S~$ such that $~S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$ where $X_k~'s$ are i.i.d random vectors for all $k~ {\geq}~ 0$ which are uniformly distributed on $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ {$\pm{e_j,~ j= 1,...,d}$} where $~e_1,...,e_d$ are the canonical basis of $Z^d$.
Obviously the expected value is zero component-wise, I know $$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow N(\overrightarrow{0}, \Sigma)$$
here comes my struggle to apply multivariate CLT, and then to arrive to $E(D) \sim \sqrt{n} \\$ . $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$Can you help me with that?, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the missing ingredient is the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem). The assertion
$$
\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\stackrel d\to Z,\tag1
$$
where $Z$ has multivariate normal $N(\vec0,\Sigma)$ distribution, is already the multivariate CLT, so apply the continuous mapping theorem to (1) using the function $g(t):=\|t\|:=(t_1^2+t_2^2+\cdots + t_d^2)^{1/2}$ (i.e., $g$ is the $d$-dimensional Euclidean norm) to conclude
$$
\left\|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\right\|\stackrel d\to \| Z\|.\tag2$$

The LHS of (2) equals $D/\sqrt n$. This may be enough for you to assert (heuristically) that $E(D)$ is roughly $\sqrt n$. In fact, you can argue further that
$$E\left(\left\|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\right\|\right)\to E(\| Z\|),\tag3
$$
an assertion that does not follow immediately from (2). A rigorous proof of (3) would note that the LHS of (2) has constant variance independent of $n$, and therefore is uniformly bounded in $L^2$, which [implies uniform integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729217/215011) and justifies (3).