# Uniform $L^p$ bound implies uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a follow-up question to the below question and response. How does the answer use the finite measure assumption?

[Uniform $L^p$ bound on finite measure implies uniform integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729217/uniform-lp-bound-on-finite-measure-implies-uniform-integrability)

Comment: its not used, the given definition of uniform integrability assumes that the space have finite measure

Comment: But if we take the assumption out of the definition, does anything go wrong? It seems like everything would work fine?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability for a definition of "uniformly integrable" in infinite measure space.

Comment: Sorry, how does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a finite measure space $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$, a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable if $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_E\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert >R\}}d\mu=0.$$

It would be tempting to use such a definition in the infinite measure space setting. However, there would be the problem that a sequence could be uniformly integrable even if none of the involved function is integrable (say constant equal to one).
Instead, the following definition is used:

> A sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable if for each positive $\varepsilon$, there exists a non-negative integrable function $g$ such that $$ \sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_E\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert >g\}}d\mu<\varepsilon.$$

This is exactly what is needed to go from convergence in measure to convergence in $L^1$.
Moreover, this coincides with the previous definition when $X$ is finite.

In the linked question, the measure space is assumed to be finite and this assumption cannot be avoided. Indeed, if the measure of $X$ is infinite, then it may be possible to find a sequence which is bounded in $L^p$ but none of the functions is integrable.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you.